# Select Contours expression - Factors of 5

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS - Trying to select contours with elevation 5,10,15,20,25, and so on.   Anyone know what expression would work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use modulo operator `%`:

```
"val" % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Introducing [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), or [remainder of division](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id46) (as QGIS calls it): You divide any integer by another, and the operator returns "what is left". E.g. `20 % 7 = 6` - 7 "fits" twice into 20, and the remainder is 6. Leading to `21 % 7 = 0` - because there is no remainder of your operation.

So, in your case you want to [select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=select%20expression#selecting-features) using something similar to

`"heigthfield" % 5 = 0`.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate an array using `generate_series()` with a step of five and check if the `value` is in that array:

```
array_contains(generate_series(5,255,5),"val")
```

You can set the minimum and the maximum value you want to select. The first argument is the start value, the second argument the end value and the third argument the step of 5.